# Transit visa to Canada with multiple layovers from the US

Tags: visas, canada, transit-visas, layovers, air-canada

I'm planning to go to Hong Kong (actually to Shenzhen, but I'll go from HG to SZ by train) from the US (I'm on an F1 visa in the US) by this route:

EWR (Newark) - YYC (Calgary) - YVR (Vancouver) - HKG (Hong Kong).

The return route is this (I don't include Shenzhen from where I'll take the train to HK):

HKG (Hong Kong) - YVR (Vancouver) - YYZ (Toronto) - EWR (Newark).

All flights are with Air Canada. I believe I do need a transit Canadian visa (I'm a citizen of Russia).

Is it fine that I have two layovers in Canada each way during my trip? Will the transit visa suffice? Are there any restrictions on terminals (e.g. if the terminal of arrival will differ from the terminal of departure)? (If yes, then by the way, how can I know the terminals beforehand? Google flights doesn't show them.)

Also, do Canadian customs officers care about for how long my US visa is valid? (It will expire one day after I enter the US when returning from HK.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Canadian transit visa is fine for your trip. It will permit you to transit landside in Canada for a stay of up to 48 hours each entry. You are allowed to leave the airport or even stay overnight if you need to do so.

Be sure that you apply for a multiple entry visa. If your return itinerary takes you through Canada, you will need the visa again, even if you do not pass through Canadian immigration (for international transfers to the US preclearance, transiting passengers now usually skip Canadian immigration).

Comment: If I'm even allowed to leave the airport, then changing terminals won't be a problem, right?

Comment: @user76396 Surely you can change terminals.